# Cannot Click CollectionViewCell to Segue to New ViewController

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview, segue, uicollectionviewcell

I have two separate UICollectionViews within a single UIViewController. Each UICollectionView is pulling data from two different arrays and is displaying them properly. However, I can't click on the UICollectionViewCell to perform a segue to another UIViewController.

I believe it has something to do with my if-else statement since I get an error message stating "Will never be executed."

I've tried moving the "didSelectItem indexPath" code to different sections within the if-else statement, before and after.

import UIKit

class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet weak var categoriesCollectionView: UICollectionView!

@IBOutlet weak var popularCollectionView: UICollectionView!

let categories = [

    "Browse All Categories",
    "cat1",
    "cat2",
    "cat3",

    ]

let categoryImages: [UIImage] = [

    UIImage(named: "img1")!,
    UIImage(named: "img2")!,
    UIImage(named: "img2")!,

]

let browsePopular = [

    "pop1",
    "pop2",
    "pop3",

]

let popularImage: [UIImage] = [

    UIImage(named: "popImg1")!,
    UIImage(named: "popImg2")!,
    UIImage(named: "popImg3")!,

]

let browsePopularDescription = [

    "popDesc1",
    "popDesc2",
    "popDesc3"

]



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    categoriesCollectionView.delegate = self
    categoriesCollectionView.dataSource = self

    popularCollectionView.delegate = self
    popularCollectionView.dataSource = self
```

//I tried moving the didSelect code at the beginning:

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let name = categories[indexPath.row]
        let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: name)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController!,  animated: true)

    }
}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
```

//Start of Category Collection View Code

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if collectionView==self.categoriesCollectionView{
        return categories.count

    }
    else{
        return browsePopular.count
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if collectionView==self.categoriesCollectionView {


    let cell: CategoriesCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellBrowseAll", for: indexPath) as! CategoriesCollectionViewCell

    cell.categoriesCollectionViewImage.image = categoryImages[indexPath.item]


    return cell
    }

    else{

        let cell: PopularCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellPop1", for: indexPath) as! PopularCollectionViewCell

        cell.browsePopular.text = browsePopular[indexPath.row]
        cell.popularImage.image = popularImage[indexPath.row]
        cell.browsePopularDescription.text = browsePopularDescription[indexPath.row]

        return cell


    }
```

//I tried adding the didSelect code at the end but I get a warning message that states: "Will never be executed"

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
       let name = categories[indexPath.row]
       let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: name)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController!,  animated: true)
   }

}
```

Expected results - the user clicks the UICollectionViewCell and segues to a new UIViewController with

Actual results - no tap recognized or code not executed

Comment: `didSelectItemAt` needs to stand on its own, not within an if-else block of one of the other methods. Within `didSelectItemAt`, you'll need to do the same check as you're doing in the other methods, `if collectionView == ...`.

Comment: You should have to use performSegue() instead of pushViewController() as you are using Segue concepts.